# [meteor][0.6.*] With meteorjs, how to download file with Meteor.http?

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app, the server try to download some file to store them on filesystem.
I use Meteor.http package to do that, but in fact, if file are downloaded, they seems to be corrupted.

```
var fileUrl = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5'; //for example
Meteor.http.call("GET", fileUrl, function funcStoreFile(error, result) {
    "use strict";
    if (!error) {
        var fstream = Npm.require('fs'),
            filename = './.meteor/public/storage/' + collectionId;

        fstream.writeFile(filename, result.content, function funcStoreFileWriteFS(err) {
            if (!err) {
                var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
                Fiber(function funcStoreImageSaveDb() {
                    MyfileCollection.update({_id: collectionId}, {$set: {fileFsPath: filename}});
                }).run();
            } else {
                console.log('error during writing file', err);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('dl file FAIL');
    }
});
```

I did a symlink from public/storage to ../.meteor/public/storage to enable direct download from url (http://localhost:3000/storage/myfileId)

When i compare the file downloaded with this system and the same file downloaded directly from a browser, they are different. What's wrong with my conception?

Comment: Are your files base64 encoded? Why do you base64 encode your content? What are their contents are they binary?

Comment: No in fact this is an old try, i remove it from the sample

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1670 is the most current attempt to fix this. Hopefully it will be merged soon.

Comment: happy to see that, no more need to use request directly with Npm

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and made a solution based on this discussion:
[on https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/905](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/905)

By using the request library, which meteor is using under the hood as well, one can avoid the problem with binary downloads. Besides I would recommend not saving small files to the filesystem but base64 encoded in mongodb directly. This is the easiest solution, if you plan to deploy to meteor.com or other cloud services. 
An other glitch I found when saving files to the public dir in development is that meteor is reloading the files for every change in the public dir. this can lead to data corruption as chunks of the file are being downloaded. Here some code i am using based on the above discussion.

```
Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")
request = Npm.require 'request'    
Meteor.methods
      downloadImage: (url) ->
        if url
          fut = new Future()
          options =
              url: url
              encoding: null
          # Get raw image binaries
          request.get options, (error, result, body) ->
              if error then return console.error error
              base64prefix = "data:" + result.headers["content-type"] + ";base64,"
              image = base64prefix + body.toString("base64")
              fut.ret image
          # pause until binaries are fully loaded
          return fut.wait()
        else false

Meteor.call 'downloadImage', url, (err, res) ->
  if res
    Movies.update({_id: id}, {$set: {image: res}})
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes in fact with this solution you avoid using the MEteor.http package.
I did the same yesterday (available on github: https://github.com/Rebolon/tutoDlFileByServer)
Thx

Comment: This will be fixed in Meteor with https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/1670/. You'll be able to do HTTP.get(url, {encoding:null}) to get a binary.

Comment: The encoding option of meteor HTTP is a sub option of npmRequestOptions, so HTTP.get(url, {npmRequestOptions: {encoding:null}} which finally allowed me to get binary files like jpg